# Dynamic sql is giving syntax error.

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am executing the following sql. I get a syntax error which is (Incorrect syntax near '=')
The query executes fine and gives proper results when executed normally. couldn't understand. plz take a look.

```
DECLARE @pvchMachineId VARCHAR(100)  = ''

DECLARE @pvchMake VARCHAR(100) = ''

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @sql = ' SELECT TOP 20 x.intId, x.vchMachineId, x.AUDenom, x.intGroupId,

x.vchMake, x.vchModel, x.mCurrency

from dbo.Machine x

inner join
(select max(m1.AUDenom) as audenom, m1.vchMachineId

from dbo.Machine m1
left JOIN dbo.ImportedFile ife on m1.intImportedFileId = ife.intId
WHERE ife.dtFileDate >= ''1-1-2013'' AND ife.dtFileDate <= ''1-29-2014'' AND

--following two lines cause the error

(' + @pvchMake + '= ''0'' OR m1.vchMake = @pvchMake) AND

(' + @pvchMachineId +'= ''0'' OR m1.vchMachineId = @pvchMachineId)

group by vchMachineId) y

on x.AUDenom = y.audenom and x.vchMachineId = y.vchMachineId 
ORDER BY x.AUDenom DESC'
```

Comment: What are the values of your variables?

Comment: how are you passing those parameters to execute statement?

Comment: Can you show non-dynamic version of your query. It an help to understand what you mean.

Comment: the best way to check dynamic sql is to use SELECT @sql  at last line

Comment: And i see comment in between you query

Comment: @HamletHakobyan following is the non-dynamic versino

Comment: @MillerKoijam Comments are fine in dynamic sql.

Comment: if the comment is in between your query and you query end with AND?

Comment: A comment with `--` in sql ends when the line ends. Same in  dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your query to the following

```
(@pvchMake = ''0'' OR m1.vchMake = @pvchMake) AND
(@pvchMachineId = ''0'' OR m1.vchMachineId = @pvchMachineId)
```

than later when you go to execute just pass it in as parameters to sp_executesql function.

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
         ,N'@pvchMachineId VARCHAR(100), @pvchMake VARCHAR(100)'
         ,@pvchMachineId,@pvchMake
```

or this which is cleaner

```
Declare @ParametersDefinition NVARCHAR(max) = N'@pvchMachineId VARCHAR(100), @pvchMake VARCHAR(100)'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @ParametersDefinition, @pvchMachineId,@pvchMake
```

In the end you do not want to concatenate your dynamic SQL statement, it opens it up for SQL Injections. Even though it is a valid option it should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: i've executed it from application as well. it works fine

Answer (score 2):

This statement :

```
'(' + @pvchMake + '= ''0'' OR m1.vchMake = @pvchMake)'
```

Will output, since the variables are not initialized by anything else than `''`  :

```
(= '0' OR m1.vchMake = @pvchMake)
```

Which is not correct syntaxically.

You should use :

```
'(''' + @pvchMake + '''= ''0'' OR m1.vchMake = @pvchMake)'
```

Which would output :

```
(''= '0' OR m1.vchMake = @pvchMake)
```

Comment: i send a 0 or '' from application if i want the OR operator to short circuit. in case a match is required, i send a string value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can make sense:

```
...

(''' + @pvchMake + '''= ''0'' OR m1.vchMake = ''' + @pvchMake +''') AND

(''' + @pvchMachineId +'''= ''0'' OR m1.vchMachineId = ''' + @pvchMachineId + ''')
...
```

Comment: +1 @THunter or you could send `''''` instead of `''`.

Comment: @THunter, You can use @SaUce solution if you want to pass  `@pvchMake` and `@pvchMake` as arguments.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan. i was making a syntax error and its working just fine with the modification